# Two time stamp string in single row to convert datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

csv include some column value is below time stamp string type, how to convert it to datetime of most recent date in pandas...

```
2019-09-27 09:15:422019-09-28 14:55:182019-09-26 04:54:12 

case[date]=case[date].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,errors = 'coerce',infer_datetime_format=True))
```

but execute with below error

```
('offset must be a timedelta strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and timedelta(hours=24).', 'occurred at index Preauth Pending Date')
```

Comment: these datetimes are in one row with no space before year `2019` ?

Comment: yes ..kindly write code to convert datetime type with recent date

Comment: There is always `2019` year?

Comment: No , there may be 2018 or previous year also..

Comment: rest column is convert to datetime format but where the two time stamp or three that raise the error...i read the every string 10 first character and then convert to datetime format but i need more easy way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-09-27 09:15:422019-09-28 14:55:182019-09-26 04:54:12']})
df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x : max([pd.to_datetime(x[i:i+19]) for i in range(0,len(x),19)]))
df['date']
```

I assume that your date format will not change here to use the size of the string to split it, before selecting the most recent date.

Comment: when i change above code to all date type column it change month to day or day to month which is mix type..

Comment: my all column dict is

Comment: {'Status Update Date': ['27/09/2019 09:06:12 AM',
  '03/09/2019 02:29:43 PM',
  '25/09/2019 09:13:45 AM',
  '23/09/2019 01:55:44 PM',
  '24/09/2019 11:00:06 AM'],
 'IP Registration Date': ['03/09/2019 04:50:55 PM',
  nan,
  '11/09/2019 01:28:23 PM',
  '20/09/2019 11:54:32 AM',
  nan],
 'Claim Pending Date': ['2019-09-26 15:51:492019-09-16 09:40:06',
  nan,
  '2019-09-24 11:59:33',
  nan,
  nan],
 'Claim Pending Updated Date': ['2019-09-27 09:06:122019-09-16 09:49:34',
  nan,
  '2019-09-25 09:13:45',
  nan,
  nan]}

Comment: I am not sure to understand your problem

Comment: Sending above is dict file in which two type's of column first is simple string type in which one timestamp  and second one is multiple timestamp from which i choose max one timestamp and convert it datetime format ..but after conversion there is problem that some place day convert in month and month convert in day.

Comment: you can sepcify a date format in `pd.to_datetime` but if different column have different format you might want to call it separately on each column

Comment: i all ready called differently...for c in df.columns:
    f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors = 'coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)
    df[c] = (df[c].str.replace(r'(\d{4}-)', r',\1')
                                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                .apply(f)
                                 .max(axis=1))

Comment: I think you should create another question if the problem is a different step from this one

Answer (score 0):

Idea is add `,` for integers with length `4` before `-` for possible split by `,`, convert to datetimes and get `max` value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-09-27 09:15:422019-09-28 14:55:182019-09-26 04:54:12',
                           '2018-09-27 09:15:422018-09-28 14:55:182020-09-26 04:54:12']})
#print (df)

f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors = 'coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)
df['last'] = (df['date'].str.replace(r'(\d{4}-)', r',\1')
                        .str.split(',', expand=True)
                        .apply(f)
                        .max(axis=1))
print (df)
                                                date                last
0  2019-09-27 09:15:422019-09-28 14:55:182019-09-... 2019-09-28 14:55:18
1  2018-09-27 09:15:422018-09-28 14:55:182020-09-... 2020-09-26 04:54:12
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'Preauth Pending Date': [nan, nan, nan, '2019-09-21 05:34:06', nan],
 'Preauth Pending Updated Date': [nan, nan, nan, '2019-09-23 10:29:05', nan],
 'Claim Pending Date': ['2019-09-26 15:51:492019-09-16 09:40:06', nan,'2019-09-24 11:59:33', nan, nan],
 'Claim Pending Updated Date': ['2019-09-27 09:06:122019-09-16 09:49:34', nan, '2019-09-25 09:13:45', nan, nan]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#print (df)

for c in df.columns:
    f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors = 'coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)
    df[c] = (df[c].str.replace(r'(\d{4}-)', r',\1')
                                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                .apply(f)
                                 .max(axis=1))
print (df)

  Preauth Pending Date Preauth Pending Updated Date  Claim Pending Date  \
0                  NaT                          NaT 2019-09-26 15:51:49   
1                  NaT                          NaT                 NaT   
2                  NaT                          NaT 2019-09-24 11:59:33   
3  2019-09-21 05:34:06          2019-09-23 10:29:05                 NaT   
4                  NaT                          NaT                 NaT   

  Claim Pending Updated Date  
0        2019-09-27 09:06:12  
1                        NaT  
2        2019-09-25 09:13:45  
3                        NaT  
4                        NaT
```

Comment: having error message "Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only"

Comment: How working `print (df['date'].str.replace(r'(\d{4}-)', r',\1'))` ?

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @Inder - What is `print (df.head().to_dict('l'))` ?

Comment: result for dict......{'Preauth Pending Date': [nan, nan, nan, '2019-09-21 05:34:06', nan],
 'Preauth Pending Updated Date': [nan, nan, nan, '2019-09-23 10:29:05', nan],
 'Claim Pending Date': ['2019-09-26 15:51:492019-09-16 09:40:06',
  nan,
  '2019-09-24 11:59:33',
  nan,
  nan],
 'Claim Pending Updated Date': ['2019-09-27 09:06:122019-09-16 09:49:34',
  nan,
  '2019-09-25 09:13:45',
  nan,
  nan]}

Comment: Thanx a lot.. This is working... for c in df.columns:
    f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors = 'coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)
    df[c] = (df[c].str.replace(r'(\d{4}-)', r',\1')
                                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                .apply(f)
                                 .max(axis=1))